# How to check if the Current Time is in between Two Given TImes?

Tags: jquery

I have got startTime and endTime and current_time , how to check if the current time is in between these two times or not ??

I have tried as following :

```
var startTime = '08:27 PM';
var endTime = '09:31 PM';
var curr_time = getval();

if (curr_time > startTime && curr_time < endTime) {
    alert("No")
} else {
    alert('Yes');
}

function getval() {
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }
    var current_time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;
    return current_time;
}
```

But always it goes to the Yes condition only .

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this issue ??

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/j4eb3xa7/2/

Comment: "if (curr_time > startTime || curr_time < endTime) {" check this link http://jsfiddle.net/j4eb3xa7/3/ this is ur need right ?

Comment: No. you are wrong. What if curr_time is 09:30PM?

Comment: Will someone care explaining why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.. This code will convert 12 hr time to 24 hr time.

```
    var startTime = '12:27 PM';
    var endTime = '12:36 PM';

    var curr_time = getval();

    if (get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(endTime)) {
      //in between these two times
      alert("Yes")
    } else {
      alert('No');
    }

    function get24Hr(time){
      var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
      var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
      if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
      if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;

      var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
      hours = hours*100+minutes;
      console.log(time +" - "+hours);
      return hours;
 }

    function getval() {
     var currentTime = new Date()
     var hours = currentTime.getHours()
     var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

     if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

     var suffix = "AM";
     if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
     }
     if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
     }
     var current_time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

     return current_time;

    }
```

Try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/jamesmalvi/2f60pye4/

Comment: Thank you very much . I thought it was a straight comparison

Answer (score 0):

So I added two functions, the first turns any normal time into military time:

```
function makeMilitary(string) {
    if (string.substr(-2) === "PM" && string.substr(0, 2) < 12)
    {
        var hour = parseInt(string.substr(0, 2));
        string = hour + 12 + string.substr(2);
    }
    else if (string.substr(-2) === "AM" && string.substr(0, 2) == 12)
    {
        string = "00" + string.substr(2);
    }
    return string;
}
```

The second uses the first to convert start, end, and current to military time, and then compares them:

```
function compare(start, end, current) {
    start = makeMilitary(start);
    end = makeMilitary(end);
    current = makeMilitary(current);

    if (start < end) // both times are in the same day
    {
        return current > start && current < end ? true : false;
    }
    else // the end time is on the day after the start time
    {
        return current > start || current < end ? true : false;
    }
}
```

It even handles a case where the start time is at the end of one day and the end time is at the beginning of the next.

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/j4eb3xa7/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use integer values for your variables current_time, startTime and endTime. Also use OR instead of AND at your if statement.